# NSString retain count -1

Tags: ios, nsstring

I want to print retain count of `NSString` in `AppDelegate` class in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] init];
NSLog(@"str retain count %d",[str retainCount]);
```

but it always gives -1 instead of +1....why ???

Comment: you would never create an string this way. why do you do it?

Comment: The first rule of using retainCount, never trust them

Comment: http://www.whentouseretaincount.com

Answer (score 4):

`NSUIntegerMax` means the returned object is immortal. This used to be in the docs, but has since been removed (because `-retainCount` is very discouraged).

In MRC, some people would actually override `-retainCount` to prevent their singletons from ever being deallocated.

In this case, it is a logical optimization for `[[NSString alloc] init]` to return a constant/immortal, rather than creating an empty string for each request. Of course, you should not rely on this detail/behavior in your program.

Comment: Please suggest me, how my answer is incorrect. I got downvote without any reason..

Comment: @AnoopVaidya i did not downvote your answer. if i had to guess: the first two sentences aren't very clear, and that's all there was to your original answer (IIRC). and yeah - i really dislike downvotes without explanations :\

Answer (score 3):

[Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/retainCount) say:

> **Special Considerations**
>
> This method is of no value in debugging memory management issues. Because any number of framework objects may have retained an object in order to hold references to it, while at the same time autorelease pools may be holding any number of deferred releases on an object, it is very unlikely that you can get useful information from this method.

So you shouldn't count on its correctness.

Also, `-1` is actually largest unsigned integer, not negative value. Retain count returns `NSUInteger`, so you should use `%u` instead of `%d`.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you should no longer use the `-retainCount` method, as pointed out by others' answers. The reason is, a lot of retain/release work is done inside the `NSString` class depending on how you create it. When you create an `NSString` you could actually be creating one of many `NSString` subclasses (the `id` return type of the initialisers is not specific).

All `NSConstantStrings` (those created by `@""`) are not releasable - they exist for the duration of the program (as specified by both gcc and clang). Thus, Apple have arbitrarily set its `retainCount` to be the highest possible unsigned integer (or -1 if it is read as signed, as it is here) because it makes no sense for a constant object, alive for the duration of the program, to *have* a retain count.

When you create an empty string in the way you have, it is likely Apple just automatically point you to the constant `@""` in memory as it takes up less space at runtime. As your object is now an `NSConstantString`, it is implemented to return a retain count of -1.

**EDIT:** Incidentally, as `NSConstantString` is a subclass of `NSString` it must implement the methods that `NSString` implements, including `-retainCount`. This is why you can actually call the `-retainCount` method on a constant string object (and why Apple make it return a special value). This inheritance relationship can be found near the bottom of the `NSString.h` header.